# Android - Setting edittext in a listview when using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, cursor

What im trying to do is change the value of 1 edittext in each listItem. i.e the DueDate is coming from database as a dateString 01/01/2016 and i want to change it to how many days are between now and then instead when it appears in the listView.

I need to get the value its set to now and send it through a method to calculate the days between now and then which is easy enough but the problem is when using a cursorAdapter theres no loop that i can edit the edittext.

**getValues Method which fills the list**

```
final String[] from = new String[]{"_id", "ProjectSubject", "ProjectTitle", "ProjectWorth", "ProjectDueDate", "ProjectDetails"};
    final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.IdText, R.id.SubjectTextList, R.id.ProjectTitleTextList, R.id.WorthText, R.id.DueDateTextList, R.id.DetailsTextList};

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.summary_list_item,cursor,from, to, 0);

    list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

**Adapter method which fetches the projects**

```
 public Cursor fetchAllProjects() {

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[]{
                    KEY_ID,
                    KEY_SUBJECT,
                    KEY_TYPE,
                    KEY_TITLE,
                    KEY_WORTH,
                    KEY_DUEDATE,
                    KEY_DETAILS,
                    KEY_EMAIL},
            null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;



}
```

Edit -

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                                  public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                                      if (columnIndex == 5) {
                                          ((TextView) dueDateText).setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex) + " modified");
                                          return true;
                                      } else {
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ViewBinder

e.g.

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if(columIndex==3) {
             ((TextView)view).setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex)+" modified");
             return true;
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i still think im wrong. Ive edited the original text. Im getting Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference which is pointing to dueDateText

Comment: sorry, I have made a typo before, for your code, replace `dueDateText` with `view`

Comment: Great. Thanks. Im fairly certain i can get it from here. Much appreciated.